# How AWS ElastiCache Redis works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I have some doubts related to AWS ElasticCache Redis behaviour.
Does it read by default from any replica nodes? Or does it require some configuration?

```
final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
template.setConnectionFactory(JedisConnectionFactory);
```

Will it work if i set cluster host name to `JedisConnectionFactory`?

Currently I am explicitly setting up only one replica host name to factory.

Comment: Read this, I think it answers most of your questions. Make sure you are looking at the sections for Redis no Memcached. https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/performance-at-scale-with-amazon-elasticache.pdf

Comment: @myron-semack, Thanks for sharing docs. It might be a dumb question.I still have this doubt, While creating connectionFactory shall I use cluster Primary Endpoint or individual replica endpoint so that my read and writes will be distributed?  I want my writes on primary and reads are from replicas. 
Cluster Configuration: Cluster disabled, 1 Primary 2 replicas.